# How can I write $\alpha^2+\alpha{x}+\beta{x}+xy-\beta^2$ as a sum or difference of up to four squares?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations, quadratic-forms

> I need to express this quadratic form
> $$\alpha^2+\alpha{x}+\beta{x}+xy-\beta^2$$
> as a sum or difference of squares. (maximum 4 squares) How could I do that? It seem so difficult for me.

I let you know what I'm looking for in these two examples:

I. $x^2+2xy-4xz-6yz-z^2=\left(x+y-2z\right)^2-\left(y+z\right)^2-\left(2z\right)^2$

II. $x^2-2xy+xz=(x-y+\frac{1}{2}z)^2-(y-\frac{1}{2}z)^2$

Please help me figure it out!

Is there any algorithm for such thing that I want?

Comment: Try eliminating one variable at a time - first deal with $\alpha$, then $\beta$ ...

Comment: discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: first example $$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 3 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: second example, this time we double the thing, use the Hessian matrix $$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$